# Redis Db - Watch if key exists or created

Tags: redis, servicestack

I'm trying Unique Index implemantation with Redis db (ServiceStack Client)

Normally

- Check Unique Index Duplication
- If Unique Index Exists RETURN WITH WARNING
- WATCH for Unique Index (for race-condition)
- Open Transaction
- Insert new record, Insert new records unique index
- Close Transaction

How can I get rid of 1st step?

WATCH for existence. I'm not related with changing of key. I'm related with creation or existance. (surely out of my transaction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to use redis just for checking duplicated then use hashset:

http://redis.io/commands#hash

how do you use the servicestack client? with native client? typed client? (then i can show you how to do that)

and use that command: http://redis.io/commands/hsetnx

Comment: No, I'm using redis for whole database.

Comment: so add more details about how you store the data, it is not clear

Comment: The hash key assures you uniqueness, so you can store the keys in a set

Comment: Yes, but requirement is different. User has username and username is unique for all users. If someone wants to create new user you have to check before is there any user with this username. But I want to send single command using transaction.

Comment: That wll work for that case, when adding to a set (one transaction) you get 1 for success and 0 for failure. so add the username/id (your unique identifier), if the result is 1 then it is a new user, else it is an existing one

Comment: If we forget transaction keyword yes it is true. But after check we need to insert User. And we dont want to override existing record also.

Comment: read that: http://redis.io/commands/hsetnx
if you use that and the user exists it won't be added. so if you will always try to add the user then only the new users will be created, and you will get an indication if the user exists

Comment: In redis db there is no exception mechanism for transactions. So even if I use it transaction can not be cancelled. Transaction is important keyword for my question.